# Execute Playwright not via test runner

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, playwright, playwright-dotnet

I've written a Playwright test but instead of running it via the test runner (NUnit), I'd like to run my Playwright code either from a console application or an ASP.NET Core background service.

What is the easiest way to setup Playwright so that it can be run without a test runner?

This is my current console app code:

```cs
using Microsoft.Playwright;

var browserTest = new Microsoft.Playwright.NUnit.BrowserTest();
var context = await browserTest.NewContext();
var page = await context.NewPageAsync();
await page.SetViewportSizeAsync(600,800);
await page.GotoAsync("https://www.google.com/");
```

...raising a `NullReferenceException` for `await browserTest.NewContext();`.

I'm using:

- .NET 7
- Chromium browser
- OS: Linux (Docker)

Comment: You can consume Playwright for .NET via the library: https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The console app has to reference the NuGet package `Microsoft.Playwright.NUnit` and must run the following startup code:

```cs
var pageTest = new PageTest();
pageTest.WorkerSetup();
await pageTest.PlaywrightSetup();
await pageTest.BrowserSetup();
await pageTest.ContextSetup();
await pageTest.PageSetup();
var page = pageTest.Page;
```

Then you can do the regular Playwright stuff:

```cs
await page.SetViewportSizeAsync(600, 800);
await page.GotoAsync("https://www.google.com/");
```

---

Even easier, as [@max-schmitt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6512681/max-schmitt) pointed out via the [official docs](https://playwright.dev/dotnet/docs/library#usage): reference the NuGet package `Microsoft.Playwright` and instantiate Playwright like this:

```cs
using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync();
var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

The second way @mu88 posted is the most correct in this case. No reason to bring in NUnit dependencies for a console app. However, I'd recommend adding a line before creating a new page:

```
IBrowserContext context = await chrome.NewContextAsync();
```

This gives you control over the specific context created. Calling browser.NewPageAsync() hides some stuff that might be necessary. The total code block would look like:

```
using var playwright = await Playwright.CreateAsync();
await using var browser = await playwright.Chromium.LaunchAsync();
IBrowserContext context = await chrome.NewContextAsync();
var page = await browser.NewPageAsync();
```